# Significant figures and uncertainty

Tags: significant-figures

A narrow-necked volumetric flask with a capacity of 200mL has an uncertainty of ±0.150mL so should the number of significant figures after the decimal point in my final answer be three or two?

Comment: I assume that you have a narrow-necked flask (Class A) with a nominal capacity of 200 ml or 250 ml since these are the only ones with a maximum permitted error of 0.150 ml. Could you please clarify? And don't omit the units!

Answer (score 2):

Giving to the uncertainty more than 2 valid digits would be a kind of statistical ignorance.

If you searched for the fundamental constants, measured with many orders of precision, the uncertainty is never published with more than 2 valid digits.

Even if there is done 100 repeated measurements, the SD uncertainty CI95% is 0.88*SD to 1.16*SD, so for 0.150 it is 0.132..0.174.

So $\pu{\pm 0.15 ml}$ would be much better.

See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/631/138724

---

Another possibility is the 0.150 (whatever unit ) is the maximal allowed deviation from the nominal value, given by the quality control. That can be achieved easily.

But then, you have no idea about the statistical distribution of the actual error, as you do not know the probability it would not pass the check.

It is quite possible the s belongs somewhere to interval 0.05..0.06 ( whatever unit ).

0.05 would mean about 0.3% would not pass.( $3\sigma$)

0.075 would mean about 5% would pass. ( $2\sigma$ )

Comment: I am curious what process would lead to triangular distribution, unless it is just  arbitrary approximation of normal distribution by triangular one as this one with base at cca 2.3 sigma.: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1374785/triangular-vs-normal-distribution

Comment: But it would return us to uncertainty of sigma. 0.150 with 3 digits must be a hard cut, not statistical one.

Comment: From QUAM:2012.P1 (EURACHEM/CITAC Guide, “Quantifying Uncertainty in Analytical Measurement”, 3rd Ed., 2012.), Example A1 on pp 38-39: "The value of the uncertainty is given without a confidence level or distribution function, so an assumption is necessary. Here, the standard uncertainty is calculated assuming a triangular distribution.  (skip little eqn).  NOTE: A triangular distribution was chosen, because in an effective production process, the nominal value is more likely than extremes. The resulting distribution is better represented by a triangular distribution than a rectangular one."

Comment: Sure, triangle one is definitely better than rectangular one :-) So sigma for the OP could be estimated as 0.15/2.3=0.065.

Comment: I think the triangular distribution just serves as a minimally informed estimate of a normal distribution: it has the centrality characteristic, but imposes nothing else.

Comment: I suppose so. But to be consistent with  error propagation rules, it is better to convert it to estimations of sigma or CI.

Comment: Actually, the little equation I skipped showed the uncertainty as the magnitude of the uncertainty divided by the square root of 6. Thus, 0.15/SQRT(6) = 0.15/2.45 = 0.061.

Comment: I suppose it is analysis of the triangular distribution variance.

Comment: You are exactly right! By the way, that QUAM Example A1 is for "Preparation of a Calibration Standard" (cadmium standard for AAS) and it is pretty good. They go through all the measurement error sources and show how to combine them into an overall measurement uncertainty.

Comment: 61 Vs 65, it is still good , considering the SD of SD.